# JAVA Optimal way to calculate 3^n - 3*2^n + 3.

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, puzzle

I am trying to calculate
((3^n) - (3*(2^n)) + 3)  for 1<=N<=109 in JAVA.

But it looks like it takes a lot of time to calculate this as per the problem statement.

```
double mul =  Math.pow(3,k);
double mul2 = Math.pow(2,k);    
double res =  ((mul - ((3* mul2)) + 3 ) % (1000000000 + 7));
```

The problems I am facing are

```
1) Time limit exceeded in java.(which should be less than 1 sec)
2) The result goes out of limit and thus provides wrong output.
```

Any suggestion to improve the code/calculation method will be helpful. As you can see the result to be displayed is to be modulo(1000000000 + 7).
Also I have tried writing my own power function in which I am doing this modulo after every multiplication, which does not help either.

Thanks

Comment: is this your homework ?

Comment: How precise do you need your calculation to be? You seem to need integer math with absolute precision -- in which case, your code hasn't the slightest chance of working: you use doubles, which have way less precision bits than what you'd need to store 3^109 (around 173 bits)... You need to work out your maths before your Java.

Comment: @BrunoReis It's all modulo 1000000007!

Comment: @laune: how's that relevant for the precision issue I mention? The OP calculates `Math.pow(3, 109)` on the first line. That method returns a double, so *necessarily* precision is lost. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)

Comment: You don't need "173 bits" if it is done using modulo arithmetic.

Comment: This naive calculation takes about 10 milliseconds on my machine.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at Guava's `LongMath`

Comment: This is not homework. But I came across this program while solving online problem. I was not able to calculate the exact result because of time and precision but was getting the right answer for lower input values.

Comment: Takes more than 1 second? I could undertand that on an embedded micro controller, but my PC (using C) will do that calculation 3 million times in one second - not that it's any use adding `3` to such large numbers.

Comment: Exponentiation details aside, you could try memoizing some of the results.

Comment: (Please keep capitalisation consistent.) If you need all the values starting with a trivial one (`n = 1`), try to build the next one from the current one. Experiment with manipulating the human readable number representations (strings) instead of (supposedly binary) machine representations.

Comment: Want the fastest solution? Use a precalculated table ;p

Comment: Rule of thumb: if it's one of those "calculate the answer modulo something" questions, you have to find a way to keep the answers of your intermediate steps "modulo something" as well. They'll make sure that any other approach runs out of memory and/or time (or is simply incorrect, such as using `double`s).

Comment: Do you mean `N <= 109` or `N <= 10^9`? If it is `109`, there should be no issues with a naive implementation with `long`s.

Comment: @laune: if you are **first** calculating 3^109, then **you would need** 173 bits to store the results. Just do the maths. If you do something smart and calculate modulo 1000000007 **before** calculate the power, **then** you wouldn't need 173 bits. But the OP did exactly what I told you: he **started** by calculating the power, therefore, with his original solution **he does need** a double to have 173 bits of precision, which is unrealistic in any platform I know about. See `harold`'s comment, 2 above this one. The OP didn't do what harold suggests. That's why he would, actually, need 173bits

Answer (score 5):

Abstain from using BigIntegers and evaluating powers from scratch, this is the naïve and inefficient approach.

Do work incrementally using modular arithmetic.

Keep two integer variables holding the values of `Aₙ:= 3ⁿ mod 1000000007`and `Bₙ:= 3×2ⁿ mod 1000000007`.

The updates are obvious: `Aₙ₊ₗ= 3×Aₙ mod 1000000007` and `Bₙ₊ₗ= 2×Bₙ mod 1000000007`.

For the modulo operations, I recommend to use comparisons instead of `%`.

You are lucky that `2×1000000007` fits in a 32 bits signed integer. But not `3×1000000007`, so I recommend to perform the multiplies by 3 as two additions.

Thus, all you have to implement is integer addition and subtraction modulo `1000000007`.

```java
private static int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x >= 1000000007 - y ? x - (1000000007 - y) : x + y;
}

private static int sub(int x, int y)
{
    return x < y ? x + (1000000007 - y) : x - y;
}

int n;
int a= 1;
int b= 3;
for (n= 1; n <= 109; n++)
{
    a= sum(sum(a, a), a);
    b= sum(b, b);
    int res= sum(sub(a, b), 3);
}
```

Comment: It fits into `long`, though.

Comment: nicely done, although the coding style hurts my eyes.

Comment: @mare In what way ? How can you judge 'style' from a handful of lines which are program fragments ?

Comment: there are sun/oracle coding conventions, e.g. method names should start with lower case, same applies for variable names and so on. most java programmers stick at least to those, so maybe it's too harsh to say it hurts my eyes I want to put it differently: "it is  an uncommon style for a java snippet"

Comment: Actually I wrote it in C++, but that's unimportant.

Comment: For n<=19 if you check the answer we get from your code is "160688599" but the correct answer will be "1160688606"

Comment: @learner: how can you show a number larger than 1000000007 and claim that it is a correct answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is JAVA independent , you need to find **a^b** efficiently for large **b**. You can do this by using modular exponentiation , complexity is **O(log(b))**.

```
  long long power(long long a,long long b)
  {
        if(b==0)return 1;
        long long ans=power(a,b/2);
        ans=(ans*ans)%1000000007;
        if(b%2)ans=(ans*a)%1000000007;
        return ans;
  }
```

The above is in c/c++ , same logic can be extended in JAVA.

**EDIT** 
Now as you need to do this for 1<=N<=109 the complexity would increase as compared to linear fashion. To avoid this look at what we have to calculate.

1. The first term makes a GP 3 , 9 ,....3^(109) so you can just replace it by **3(3^(109)-1)/2**, so just calculate 3^(109) MOD 1000000007 once by calling the power function.(You would need to calculate MOD inverse of 2  also)
   .So this takes O(log(109)).
2. The second term is also a GP and can be done in a similar way.
3. The last term is just 3*109

Comment: This isn't going to help with the speed since it must be calculated for 1 <= n <= 109 anyway. So using your method would just slow it down.

Comment: @laune now it will be O(log(n))

Comment: You are using an `O(N Log(N))` approach where `O(N)` is easily achived.

Comment: @migdal: please read carefully. Computing for all `N` makes it `O(N Log(N))`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust basically reduce the expression by using gemetric progression and then I just have to call the power function twice, hope I cleared the doubt

Comment: After all the question is slightly ambiguous. If the value is to be returned for a single value in range`[1,109]`, then tabulating the function is a very good way, as said by FabioMarcolini; it is `O(1)`. If all values are to be computed (for instance to build this table :) ), then the iterative `O(N)` approach can be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the BigInteger class for better precision.
 eg

```
private static final BigInteger TWO = new BigInteger("2");
private static final BigInteger THREE = new BigInteger("3");

//input n, m (modulo)
public static BigInteger getResult(BigInteger n, BigInteger m) {
    BigInteger a = THREE.modPow(n, m);
    BigInteger b = TWO.modPow(n, m);

    return a.subtract(THREE.multiply(b)).add(THREE).mod(m);

}
```

*If you use it inside a for loop, you may gain some advantage from precomputations, as every next `n` may use the results of the previous `n-1` calculations. Eg 3^n could be computed as 3^(n-1)*3

Comment: This will also be too slow - much, much slower than double. -1

Answer (score 0):

You face two issues, both can be adressed by using BigInteger. First, BigInteger is capable of holding your values and secondly it already implements a method to perform modular exponentiation namley:

```
BigInteger  modPow(BigInteger exponent, BigInteger m)
```

which returns a BigInteger whose value is (this^exponent mod m).

If you are interested on the other hand, why it doesn't work (i.e. is too slow) I would recommend you the following article explaining efficent integer exponention [article](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/03/21/efficient-integer-exponentiation-algorithms)

Comment: The way BigInteger is implemented, I suspect that this will be too slow, too. It's a pity we don't know the time limit.

Comment: 1) it is implemented very efficent 2) the time limit is 1 second, which is time enough to di it this whay ore than 100 times on my machine.

Comment: BigInteger is not the most efficient implementation for multiple precision integers. It has some advantages over alternative techniques, but maximum speed is not one of them. Although one second may be enough for this problem, if coded well enough.